# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference (PHP PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

Currently, I created an android system. I uses PHP as a connector from android to MySQL Database. I also Used PDO method.

In this app, there's a list view. Unfortunately, the listview cannot appear and when I uses log, the error state:

Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference at line 17

Below is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status FROM report WHERE badgeid = :badgeid' AND report_status = :report_status;");

$stmt->bindParam(':badgeid',$userid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':report_status',"Pending",PDO::PARAM_STR); //line 17
$stmt->execute();
```

Can anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), the second parameter is the reference to a variable, you are passing a string value, therefore it throws an error.

To fix it, either create a variable to hold that value

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status 
                        FROM report WHERE badgeid = :badgeid' AND report_status = :report_status;");

$stmt->bindParam(':badgeid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':report_status', $status = "Pending", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or since you always select report with status `Pending`, don't make it as a parameter

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status 
                        FROM report WHERE badgeid = :badgeid' AND report_status = 'Pending';");

$stmt->bindParam(':badgeid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks dude!

Comment: @user11934869: glad that I help :)

Comment: can you help me to solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298767/android-php-undefined-variable-at-php-site-when-want-to-display-listview-a