# Android / PHP: Undefined variable at PHP site when want to display ListView at Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo

Currently, I developed an app that has ListView. The listView is retrieved from the MySQL database. To connect it, I used PHP and PDO function. When I run the apps it will display an error:

> JSONException: Value br of type `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to JSONObject

Now, i used log.d to trace the error and got this:

1)  Undefined variable: report_date in line 27

2)  `{"data":[{"report_id":[],"task_name":[],"badgeid":[],"report_date":"01 Jan 1970","photo_before":[],"photo_after":[],"report_status":[]}]}`

It should display 3 report_id (based on data at MySQL database).

Below is my PHP Code:

```
<?php 

    require_once 'configPDO.php';

    $userid = $_GET["badgeid"] ?? "";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status FROM report WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND report_status = 'Pending'");   
    $stmt->bindParam(':badgeid',$userid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $task = array();

    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($result) {
        $result = array();
        $temp['report_id'] = $result; 
        $temp['task_name'] = $result; 
        $temp['badgeid'] = $result;

        $booked = strtotime($report_date);
        $report_date = date("d M Y", $booked);

        $temp['report_date'] = $report_date;
        $temp['photo_before'] = $result;
        $temp['photo_after'] = $result;
        $temp['report_status'] = $result; 
        array_push($task, $temp);
    }

    $response = array();
    $response["data"] = $task;

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: `$booked = strtotime($report_date);` you haven't defined `$report_date` before this line, so PHP will complain `Undefined variable: report_date`

Comment: @catcon, thus, i need to change what?